# use NSSpeechRecognizer class in PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa, pyobjc

I was trying to use OS X built-in speech recognition engine in python through PyObjC.

```
class Recognizer(NSSpeechRecognizer):

    def __init__(self):

        cmds = ['computer', 'keyboard']
        self.setCommands_(cmds)
        self.setDelegate_(self)

        self.blocksOtherRecognizers = True
        self.listensInForegroundOnly = False

        return self

recognizer = Recognizer.alloc().init()
```

**Question1:** Do I need to assign delegate to another class?

**Question2:** Do I need to initialize instance recognizer in the class **init** method?

```
def speechRecognizer_didRecognizeCommand_(sender, command):

    if command == 'computer':
        print('computer')
```

**Question3:** Should I define this inside the class Recognizer or not?

```
recognizer.startListening()
```

**Question4:** There was no sign for the recognizer was listening when I run the script, the script finished immediately.

```
speechRecognizer_didRecognizeCommand_(sender, command)
```

**Question5:**I don't know what to put in the second argument *command* because I feel like it's the message it receives from recognizer instead of something I should put in.

That's it. As you can see I'm really confused right now. I'm greatly appreciate for answers, thank you.

Also if you have any other solution of voice recognition besides this cocoa class please tell me.

links:

[NSSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSpeechRecognizer/startListening)

[Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Speech/Articles/RecognizeSpeech.html)

Comment: I think you are trying to ask **way too much** in a single post, could you try to narrow down what you actually want answered?

Comment: I shrieked it a lot, hope this will work, because I think it will be harder to understand if I split it.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of issues with your example:

- Don't use `__init__` as the initialiser, use `init` instead. That's needed because PyObjC follows Cocoa's conventions instead of the normal Python conventions.
- I wouldn't subclass `NSSpeechRecognizer`, but would use a separate delegate class which is more in line with the normal Cocoa style.
- You cannot use assignment to set properties like you're trying to do, use explicit calls to the setter instead. That is `self.setBlocksOtherRecognizers(True)` instead of `self.blocksOtherRecognizers = True`.

  The reason for that is that in Objective-C methods and properties live in two different namespaces, while they live in the same namespace in Python and you cannot have a method an property with the same name (`self.blocksOtherRecognizers` is the getter method for the property).
- And finally, you need to start a runloop to actually use the recogniser:

  `loop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
  loop.run()`

A complete example:

```
from Cocoa import NSObject, NSSpeechRecognizer, NSRunLoop

class Controller (NSObject):
    def init(self):
        commands = [ "up", "down" ]

        self.recognizer = NSSpeechRecognizer.alloc().init()
        self.recognizer.setCommands_(commands)
        self.recognizer.startListening()
        self.recognizer.setDelegate_(self)

    def speechRecognizer_didRecognizeCommand_(self, recognizer, command):
        print(command)

controller = Controller.alloc().init()
loop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
loop.run()
```

Note that this example won't stop, you will have to kill it forcefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really helpful and I learned a lot. I'll update as soon as I get to try it on my computer.

Comment: So I've tried the code and dictation icon pop up. But it can't recognize the command. I clicked the "show" button and can't find my command. It is possible that it's because of my library isn't complete? I follow the manual install on https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html and installed all three packages : core, cocoa frame, and quartz frame, but I didn't install "all other packages (in arbitrary order)".

Comment: I'm not sure. The script works for me (OSX 10.11 with the latest release of PyObjC).  It shouldn't be necessary to install anything beyond core and the Cocoa wrappers.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to figure it out.